# UIScrollView wont scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a UIScrollView set up like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

created a scroll view in IB and connected it to the property on top. The width and height are set in IB (there set to W:756 H:468
created the scroll views content size and set scroll enabled

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

also, I am setting this in a view where the view controller is a subview of a other view. This view is set up using a NIB and the the view where I am adding this subview is in a story board.

Comment: This phrase doesn't actually make sense: *the view controller is a subview of a other view controller.*  View controllers don't have subviews; views have subviews...and their subviews are views, not view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had clicked on "Use Autolayout" inside File inspector by mistake, This caused my scroll view  not to scroll even with having a bigger content size.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the frame of the scrollView?

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 480.0f);
sefl.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(1000.0F, 1000.0F);
```

Comment: I have tried this before posting, didn't work either.

Comment: It worked for me tho. scrollview.frame is the frame of the visible view. As long as the frame is smaller than the contentSize, it should scroll. Maybe try set scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES, and scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES, so the scrollview always scrolls even if the contentsize is smaller than the frame.

Answer (score 0):

please check your scroll view content is longer that height or width size. Otherwise you will not see scrolling effect!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Instead of putting all the contents in UIScrollView, I had a separate view for that, and added that separate view to UIScrollView.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
```

Then in my viewDidLoad, I have something like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.bounds.size;
}
```